# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm getting the error

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 55

When I try to submit a simple email form to

```
public function postContact(Request $request)
{
    // code
}
```

But it never gets to the code part. So I tried comparing the values in the get method like so:

```
public function getContact(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->session()->token();
    return view('contact');
}
```

Then I compared to the value stored in the hidden field *name=_token* inside the form and they return the same value.

After that I backtracked to the method where the exception is thrown:

> /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

And echoed the test thats failing:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    echo ($this->isReading($request) ? 'true' : 'false') . ' - ' . ($this->shouldPassThrough($request)? 'true' : 'false') . ' - ' . ($this->tokensMatch($request) ? 'true' : 'false');

    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->shouldPassThrough($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request)) {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
```

And the result was:

> false - false - false

I'm all out of ideas.

I always clear the cookies before a test, I've changed all the permissions to read/write and I've added the meta *name=csrf-token* inside the head tag with the token.

EDIT:

Both

```
$request->input('_token')
```

And

```
$request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')
```

Inside handle() are null... how come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `enctype="text/plain"` from the form tag. That goes to show you: when a framework offers you idiot-proof renderers like Form::open(), just use it.

Answer (score 1):

In your form (view) file. add these two lines. I hope it would work.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('your action URL') }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ session()->getToken() }}">
```

Comment: Because of your suggestion I've found out that the problem was with the attribute *enctype="text/plain"* in the form! TYVM!

Comment: please edit this answer or, post your own answer with complete code that you fixed the problem.so next programmer who gets the same issue can fix it quickly.

Comment: An edit in my own question explaining what I did would suffice?

Comment: no, you better to post your complete answer. so it will not be confusing.

Comment: yes, I had seen..do not add it to your question. please post it as an answer.